# how to remove content from page in php

Tags: php

i got one page from curl which contain

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ipinfo xmlns="http://data.quova.com/1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

i want to delete this header
so need help how to do that .

i tried str_replace function but no success

```
$find1='/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>/';
$find2='/<ipinfo xmlns="http://data.quova.com/1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">/';
$contentx = str_replace($find1, '', $data,$count);
```

Comment: No need for delimiters in `str_replace`, it's not a regex function

Comment: Why do you have `/` before the after/before the quotes?

Comment: `str_replace()` should succeed as you have it if you remove the regex delimiters.

Comment: It might be an idea to use one of PHP's [XML extensions](http://php.net/refs.xml) to get what you do want, rather than string replacing what you do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use '/ /' delimiters with str_replace, only with regular expression functions. Remove the slashes at start and end.

In other words:

```
$find1='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$find2='<ipinfo xmlns="http://data.quova.com/1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">';
$contentx = str_replace($find1, '', $data,$count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easier using the `explode()` function.

```
$dataArray = explode("\r\n", $data, 3); // adjust the delimiter if it's unix newline
$contentx = $dataArray[2];
```